# R: Is there a way to insert rows that complete a year sequence?

Tags: r, date, sequence, rows, survival-analysis

I am working on R with a longitudinal database (register data so pretty large) about individuals, with several rows per ID (named "vn" in the database) and their attributes in column. My variable "observation" indicates each year of observation. Sometimes (but not in all cases) one or more years are skipped because nothing changes for the individual. I would like to add those "missing rows" to my database so that each individual has an entry for every year between their first and last observation (which aren't necessarily the same for everyone). Since individual's attributes can change over time, the row added must include the same attribute values as the previous one (for the example below, if a row is added for 2010, the individual will have a value of 3 in maritalstatus and 5584 in municipality).

Here is an overview of an individual in my database:

```
structure(list(vn = c("555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555"), municipality = c(5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5611, 5611, 5584, 5584, 5584), yearofbirth = c(1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957), sex = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), maritalstatus = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), observation = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2012)), row.names = 470:480, class = "data.frame")
```

My current code (below) adds rows to my dataset when an observation year is missing, keeping all the information from the previous row except that now, some information is doubled, some observation years appear twice.

`test<-test %>% expand(vn, municipality, yearofbirth, sex, maritalstatus, full_seq(observation,1))`

I was also thinking of using `rep()` but can't find a way to do what I want.

Does anyone have an idea for a code that could help me?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your data with `dput(head(vn))`so that others can reproduce your situation on their system? Please make sure that at least one of the observations in the sample has missing rows. If not, add the `n`argument to `head`to make sure youget a larger sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have at least one observation per year then this could be achieved via `tidyr::complete` and `tidyr::fill` like so:

**Edit 1**: If not all years are present in the dataset the approach still works by first converting `observation` to `factor` with the levels set to the range of years:

**Edit 2**: To take account of differing year ranges one has to filter after the fill. To this end I added a variable last_obs containing the last year observed for an individual. This variable can be used to filter after the fill.

```r
<!-- language-all: lang-r -->


d <- structure(list(vn = c("555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555", "555"), municipality = c(5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5586, 5611, 5611, 5584, 5584, 5584), yearofbirth = c(1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957), sex = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), maritalstatus = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), observation = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2012)), row.names = 470:480, class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Add some data
d1 <- d %>%
  mutate(vn = "556") %>% 
  filter(observation <= 2010, observation %% 2 == 0)

# Bind data
d2 <- bind_rows(d, d1)

d2 %>%
  # Add year of last obs by vn
  group_by(vn) %>% 
  mutate(last_obs = last(observation)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # Convert to fct
  mutate(observation = factor(observation, levels = 2000:2016)) %>%
  # Complete and fill
  tidyr::complete(vn, observation) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(everything()) %>%
  # Convert back to numeric
  mutate(observation = as.integer(as.character(observation))) %>%
  # Drop obs after year of last obs
  filter(as.numeric(observation) <= last_obs) %>% 
  # Drop helper
  select(-last_obs)
#> # A tibble: 22 x 6
#>    vn    observation municipality yearofbirth   sex maritalstatus
#>    <chr>       <int>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 555          2000         5586        1957     2             2
#>  2 555          2001         5586        1957     2             2
#>  3 555          2002         5586        1957     2             3
#>  4 555          2003         5586        1957     2             3
#>  5 555          2004         5586        1957     2             3
#>  6 555          2005         5586        1957     2             3
#>  7 555          2006         5611        1957     2             3
#>  8 555          2007         5611        1957     2             3
#>  9 555          2008         5584        1957     2             3
#> 10 555          2009         5584        1957     2             3
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

Comment: Hei thank you! But when I use your code (`test %>%tidyr::complete(vn, observation) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(everything())`) on my database, it doesn't add any rows. For the overview I gave above, it doesn't add the years 2010 and 2011. 
I thought maybe it was the structure of my variables that was the problem (originally "vn" was in chr and "observation" numeric, so I change them all in numeric), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yep. tidyr::complete completes the dataset only if we have at least one obs per in the dataset. As in my example data. I just made an edit to account for the case when not all years are present in the dataset.

Comment: It's working now, thank you very much :-) but I still have the problem that not all individuals necessarily have observations from 2000 to 2012. Some may start after 2000 and some may end before or after 2012 (and the total observation time is not the same for all).

Comment: I added another edit to take account of differing end years. Based on this approach it should be an easy task to adjust the code to take account of differing start years. Just use `first` instead of `last`.